# why does the model s use multiple batteries?

Tags: power, safety, charge, batteries

The Tesla Model S and NASA's Robonaut both use a battery pack that consists of an array of hundreds of battery cells.

Why don't the engineers just create one giant cell?

Comment: Because designing and fabricating a new type of cell from scratch has a lot of engineering risk.  So, it's either that, or creating large banks of existing battery cells.  Tesla roadster, for example, had 8000 (eight thousand) cells (18650 size).  Now that Tesla Motors have reached high enough production numbers, they are developing larger cells too.  Of course, that's going to take some time.

Comment: Because chemistry is hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The voltage out of a single battery cell is a function of the battery chemistry.  For example, carbon-zinc cells generate about 1.5 volts as does alkaline.  Lead acid cells are about 2.2 volts and so on. For an electric car, the power required would necessitate having currents of hundreds and even thousands of amperes if only a single cell was used.  This would require very heavy cables and would be very inefficient as a significant amount of the battery energy would be wasted in the cables.  For this reason, these cars use a large number of cells in series to produce several hundred volts.  This reduces the magnitude of the current and hence the cabling to manageable levels. Even a simple 9 volt transistor battery uses 6 cells in series because there is no simple battery chemistry that will directly generate 9 volts.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is self nullifying:

> Why don't the engineers just create one giant battery?

Google: "define: battery"

> Battery
>
> /noun/
>
> a container consisting of one or more cells, in which chemical energy is converted into electricity and used as a source of power.

A battery is a collection of cells.  So that is exactly what they have done. They have created a giant battery.

A battery is made of cells. A cell gives a small amount of power. Combine the cells together and you have a battery that gives a large amount of power.

It's like building a house.

Would you rather:

a) build it from bricks you can buy from the brickyard, or

b) build it out of one gigantic brick you then have to hollow out by hand to make your house?

Comment: My wife is an architect, she would love the idea of taking a gigantic brick and carving our house into...

Answer (score 1):

A battery consists of a number of individual cells, usually connected in series, although sometimes several groups of series-connected cells may be connected in parallel, depending on the required battery capacity, and practical sizes of the cells.

It may be more practical to use individual cells, rather than use a pre-assembled battery containing several cells.  The individual cells may be more easily arranged to fit in awkwardly-shaped spaces, and if one cell fails, you only have to replace that one cell, rather than the whole battery.